# Do Kafka's parallelism concepts apply when running in console mode?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, kafka-partition

So, I am new to Kafka and I have been reading about it for a while. I found this information on confluent.

https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/architecture.html

So what I understood from this is, say I have a topic called plain_text where I just send a bunch of records as plain text and I just have one broker with a single topic and single partition. I now start 2 consumer instances ConsumerA and ConsumerB. Since my partition count is less than the consumer count only one of the consumers should actively consume the messages leaving the other in an idle state. Please correct me if I am wrong.

I ran a test using the kafka-console-* scripts

#### start a zookeeper cluster

```sh
bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
```

#### start a kafka broker on localhost:9092

```
bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
```

#### create a topic plain_text with one partition

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create \
    --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 \
    --replication-factor 1 \
    --partitions 1 \
    --topic plain_text
```

#### start a producer

```
bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic plain_text
```

#### start 2 consumers belonging to the same group (run the same command twice)

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 \
    --topic plain_text \
    --formatter kafka.tools.DefaultMessageFormatter \
    --property print.key=true \
    --property print.value=true \
    --property group.id=test_group \
```

So one of the two consumers should own that single partition (again please correct me if I am wrong), but whatever I produce on the producer console is visible on both consumer consoles. Why is that both consumers are consuming messages from a single partition. Is there something I am missing or do different rules apply to the kafka-console-* scripts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If not specified, each kafka-console-consumer run will create a different consumer group id, you can check this using:

```
kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --list | grep console-consume
console-consumer-68642
console-consumer-30430
```

You can add `--group your_group_name` or `--consumer-property group.id=your_group_name` to specifically register `group.id` for your console consumers

Comment: I have edited it, I had forgotten to mention the group.id in my command.

Comment: @Shubhangb nice, I have edited to add  a separated update section in your question about what you change so others does not misunderstand. Thanks